# several subpages with same topbar

Tags: php, html

I have a **webpage with several subdirectories** for example /search or /friends. **Each** of this **subpages** has its **own javascript and css** files. Now I **want all this pages to have the same topbar** so if I wanted to change the topbar I would only have to do this in one single place.
**What's the common way of doing this?** Simple php drops out because of the several scripts and css files. My idea was to call a php script via ajax on each subpage and append the returning string to the body element with jquery's append method but this doesn't seem very clean to me.
**How does facebook handle this?** Facebook's topbar doesn't even blink when clicking an internal link.

Thanks.

Comment: What about including an header.php in all the page where you want to display your top bar?

Comment: I'm quite new to php how would i do this?

Comment: Create a file with top bar and save it as `header.php` and then in your index.php just place `include('header.php');` repeat second step for each page where you want to have your top bar

Comment: seems to be pretty simple..
thank you (:

Comment: @Fabio that should have been an answer :)

Comment: @Adrian lol i still can post it and OP can accept it :P

Comment: @Fabio You can't "accept" a comment, you can only accept an answer. They might be able to use it to solve the problem, but as far as being useful to other people who find this question by web search, it would be a lot more useful to have the correct answer *in an answer*. Since that's the point of SO (hence questions not of value outside of the OP's situation being flagged & closed), it seems the best way to go to me. Of course, do as thou wilt.

Comment: @Adrian i did it but it seems OP chose the other anser

Comment: sorry fabio didn't notice your answer of course yours is the top answer (;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using an header.php in all the pages where you want to show your top bar?
To do this just create a file with top bar and save it as `header.php` and then in your index.php just place `include('header.php');` repeat second step for each page where you want to have your top bar.

Answer (score 3):

**header.php**

```
// top bar stuff
echo '<ul><li>Link</li><li>Link</li></ul>'; //etc
```

**Other Pages**

```
<?php

include 'header.php';

?>
```